# service to auto generate and host yardocs?

Tags: yard, yardoc

Is there a service that can pull from our github repo and generate and host our yard docs?

It seems my team never looks at our docs since they have to generate them locally and then navigate to them. This is also causing them to stop writing helpful documentation in Yard format.

Something like http://www.rubydoc.info/ but with an ability to have a private documentation only my team can access.

Comment: IMO, this is more a human problem than a technical one. "My team can't be bothered to write documentation" probably won't be fixed by having them auto-built.

Comment: @ceejayoz you might be right but I do agree with the idea that an auto generated and hosted site would be very nice, so I am asking.